# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

В Gulp пытаюсь сделать build gulp а мне выдает вот такую ерунду:

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Что это может быть???

Comment: Возможно, это утечка памяти

Comment: Закиньте stack trace сюда, полный вывод ошибки.